# duplicate creation on same unit shouldn't be allowed using flow

Tags: visual-workflow, duplicate-management, custom

***If contract is in Approved status, then New Contract creation on the same unit is not
allowed***.
**contract is lookup field for unit object.**
how can I achieve that using **flow** can any one give me basic idea. below is the er diagram how they are connected with each other.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you can follow these steps i hope this will work for you.

1. Create flow on Unit creation (Record Triggered Flow).
2. Check it contains ContractId or not. (From Decision Element).
3. If its contains then store **ContractId** in flow variable.
4. Using **GetRecords** Element get Data for Contract using **ContractId**.
5. Make **decision** if its status is 'Approved' then throw an error.

Comment: sorry, I didn't get u. can u tell me in more details. please help me.